# Why are $R^n$ treated as $R^{n+1}$ spaces in $R^{n+1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

$y = x$ is a line in $R^2$ space.

But if you graph $z = x$ in $R^3$ space, [it's a plane](http://www.math.uri.edu/~bkaskosz/flashmo/graph3d/):

Both functions have the same relations, so why is one a plane but the other a line?

Comment: No, if you graph $z = x$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it is a plane.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Your right, corrected it.

Comment: I think you're confusion results from this: if you graph $y = x$ in $\mathbb R^3$, it's also a plane.

Comment: They are both [hyperplanes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the relation isn't really the same. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, you have 2 "coordinates", namely $x$ and $y$, while in $\mathbb{R}^3$ you have 3 coordinates $x,y,z$. In particular, when you consider $x = z$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the $y$ coordinate is free to be anything. Thus you obtain a plane, rather than a line. If you want a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you could fix $y$; for example $x=z$ and $y=1$ will give you a line.

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$ the set is given by
$$
\{(x,x)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
This is only one dimensional, as it depends on only one variable.  But, in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the set is given by
$$
\{(x,x,z)\,|\, x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}.
$$
This depends on two variables and will therefore be two-dimensional, hence a plane.